# Typo3 GP Variables in Form

Tags: forms, variables, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I created a COA_INT like this:

```
lib.linguasitoparametrol = COA_INT
lib.linguasitoparametrol {
  10 = TEXT
  10.stdWrap.data = GP:L

}
```

I print in fluid like so:

```
Value = {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.linguasitoparametrol')}
```

Result is: `Value = 0` or `Value = 1`.
Ok it works.

Now i want to write the variable in a input area so i write:

```
<f:form.textarea name="search[languageUid]" value="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.linguasitoparametrol')}" />
```

But i obtain in input value `<!--INT_SCRIPT.5e0cf67ea790e31ff7adaa744a7a992c-->`

Why? how can i solve it?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: I use version 7.6.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<!--INT_SCRIPT.5e0cf67ea790e31ff7adaa744a7a992c-->`should only displayed if you do not cache the page witch contain your template.

`<!--INT_SCRIPT.5e0cf67ea790e31ff7adaa744a7a992c-->` Is an placeholder for you content that is replaced after cache has build.

You dont need for GP:L a COA_INT object: When you have multiple languages you have allready typoscript conditions for these. So your Cache is build for each of these. The Cache for L=1 is allways different than the cache for L=2.

I would recommend to use it without use of COA:

```
lib.linguasitoparametrol = TEXT
lib.linguasitoparametrol.data = GP:L
```

Alternative if you use it in an Fluid Template you can pass the information via `variables`:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  template = FILE
  template.file = fileadmin/templates/MyTemplate.html
  partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/partial/
  variables {
    currentLangUid = TEXT
    currentLangUid.data = GP:L
  }
}
```

And use it in your Fluid Template by `{currentLangUid}`, so you dont have to use the cObject Viewhelper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i used GP:L just for test. anyway there is no solution? how can i write my custom no-cached variable in value of the form?